# What is the name of the movie in which eating and toilet taboos are reversed

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

Can anyone identify a (possibly French) film where the cultural taboos about going to the toilet and eating (not at the same time!) are reversed?

I remember seeing a scene with someone knocking on a door to an eating room, finding that someone was already in there eating their dinner, and being embarrassed, as if it was actually a toilet (restroom). They were quite happy going to the toilet together however.

Does that ring any bells?

This may actually be a TV programme, rather than a film, so I hope that's still acceptable.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Luis Buñuel's [Le fantôme de la liberté](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071487/plotsummary) (The Phantom of Liberty) (1974):

> One of Luis Bunuel's most free-form and purely Surrealist films,
>   consisting of a series of only vaguely related episodes - most
>   famously, the dinner party scene where people sit on lavatories round
>   a dinner table on, occasionally retiring to a little room to eat.

The scene you are looking for is available on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6boxoksi3U).