# What was the first movie to feature a person seated on a toilet?

Tags: first-appearance

[Psycho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psycho_(1960_film)) directed by Alfred Hitchcock has a scene where a person is flushing a toilet. This fact provided some shock effect, since toilets were virtually never seen in American cinema in the 1960s.

Like the title of this question says, I want to know: **which was the first movie to feature a person sitting on a toilet?**

Why I'm asking this? I think it's an interesting and funny fact.

Comment: An odd one. :) Would an outhouse suffice?

Comment: Probably not the first, but there's a great scene in Buñuel's _The Phantom of Liberty_. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1Mptgi23YE).

Comment: @Fruitbat The scene is available at http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/633/eating-and-toilet-taboos-are-reversed/637#637

Comment: I don't understand the close votes :-/ It would help if you leave a comment

Comment: Obligatory Tywin Lannister reference here.

Answer (score 15):

As a starting point, IMDB has a rather marvelous feature called "keywords" where users create tags for possible features of a film then tag films that contain such scenes or elements. It's a fun way to explore questions like this.

[Sitting on a toilet](http://www.imdb.com/search/keyword?keywords=sitting-on-a-toilet) (126 titles) is indeed such a tag. If we sort that list by date, the earliest "sitting on toilet" film is, apparently, a **1968** French comedy about cannibals who run a vegetarian restaurant (no, really!), called [A Taste For Women](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0057827/?ref_=kw_li_tt).

---

If we take [the list simply tagged "toilet"](http://www.imdb.com/search/keyword?keywords=toilet&sort=release_date,asc&mode=detail&page=1) and sort it by date, IMDB believes the earliest film containing a toilet-related scene or plot was a German drama from **1924** called [The Last Laugh](http://www.imdb.com/search/keyword?keywords=toilet&sort=release_date,asc&mode=detail&page=1), about a hotel doorman trying to deal with the indignity of being demoted to washroom attendant.

The earliest American "toilet" film does actually appear to be Psycho, 1960.

---

Here's a list of the dizzying, worrying variety of [IMDB keywords that contain the word "toilet"](http://www.imdb.com/find?s=kw&ref_=kw_fnd&q=Toilet), which range from [Head in a toilet](http://www.imdb.com/keyword/head-in-a-toilet/?ref_=fn_kw_kw_43) (32 titles) to [Toilet twerking](http://www.imdb.com/keyword/toilet-twerking/?ref_=fn_kw_kw_88) (just one title...).

If you ever wanted to know the most popular film where toilet paper makes a notable appearance, according to IMDB, it's V For Vendetta. No, I don't remember the toilet paper scene, either, but some diligent IMDB user has tagged [148 films that include toilet paper](http://www.imdb.com/search/keyword?keywords=toilet-paper). The internet is a wonderful and terrifying thing.

---

Researching this question has given me a very strange recent internet browsing history... Fun fact: I found out about this feature after a talk by director Edgar Wright, who described reading his own films' IMDB profiles and cracking up in baffled hysterics on discovering which elements the people of IMDB felt worth tagging. For example, [Shaun Of The Dead has among its "plot keywords"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0365748/keywords?ref_=tt_stry_kw) "Cricket bat", "Arab grocer" and "Hip hop montage".

Comment: You sound very similarly to Randall, author of xkcd. See : https://what-if.xkcd.com/100/

Comment: Nice answer. Have a bounty.

Answer (score 6):

In the movie 'Fun with Dick and Jane' 1977, Jane Fonda sits down on a toilet whilst Dick is in the bathroom with her and the conversation is accompanied by the sound of pee hitting the water. I'm not sure that this was the first toilet but it's the first time I have heard a woman pee on a movie soundtrack.

Answer (score 1):

1958 "In the middle of the night" with Frederick March and Kim Novak. There is even toilet paper in the shot too!